# Need to find appropriate statistical test for a longitudinal intervention study

Tags: intervention-analysis

The study: Comparing two groups (intervention vs control) across time using a behavioral measure as the outcome variable of interest.  I will have baseline behavioral measurements as well as more than 2 time points throughout treatment.  I'm interested in finding any significant improvements from baseline across time (within each group) and whether or not there were significant differences between groups.  Would this be a repeated measures ANOVA or MLM? Would I need to control for baseline behavioral measurement? Thank you in advance for any help with this!!